# Development lines in GIT

Tags: git, perforce

I'm coming from the Perforce world and now getting to grips with the Git world and have the following question which is to do with having a local repo...

One of the things I like about P4 is my dev line is kept on a server, so I don't have to backup my submits (commits in Git speak I think)... the guys providing the P4 server do this for me... very nice of of them.

Now I've started using github and bitbucket. I can clone a remote, branch a dev line and work on it locally, but I'd also like to have my development branch on say, github, so I can push changes up to their servers and back my local repo up, but not interfere with the master repo whilst I'm developing.

So, my question is how do I do this? Does this happen much in the distributed world of version control or does the local developer just have to be more careful about backing up his local branches?...
Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, everybody would want their code, even the development branch backed up somewhere. Not just for backup, but also to be accessible from their other computers.

Let's take the following scenario:

```
~ $ git clone git@github.com:User/Repo local_repo
~/local_repo (master)$ cd local_repo
~/local_repo (master)$ git checkout -b dev
~/local_repo (dev)$ touch new_file
~/local_repo (dev)$ git add new_file
~/local_repo (dev)$ git commit
```

Now you have a local clone of a remote on github with a new branch `dev` where you have made some changes.

Now there are two scenarios:

1. `User` is you and it's ok if you have `dev` in your github clone. This is simply done by:

   ```
   ~/local_repo (anything)$ git push origin dev
   ```

   which tells git to push the `dev` branch to origin.
2. You can't push to `origin` or you don't want to pollute it with your branches. In such a case, you need to make another remote somewhere, for example:

   ```
   ~ $ git clone --bare local_repo /address/to/another/remote
   ~/local_repo (anything)$ cd local_repo
   ~/local_repo (anything)$ git remote add personal /address/to/another/remote
   ~/local_repo (anything)$ git push personal dev
   ```

   `/address/to/another/remote` could be any address git can understand and has permission to write. If unsure, you can simply clone to a nearby directory, copy the directory to your server and give the new address to `git remote add`. Alternatively, you can make an unofficial clone of your own project on github (see one method [here](http://bitdrift.com/post/4534738938/fork-your-own-project-on-github)) and add the address to that as a remote.

Comment: It probably makes most sense to keep all together, so OP can mix and match at will. For multiuser projects, come up with some convention, like "Joe Random's personal branches live under `jr/`, they are off-limits for writing (and reading?) by others"

Comment: @vonbrand, I'm pretty sure people are divided on that idea. Some people strongly feel that they should keep their private branches off of the main repository, while others try to solve the name clashes with the method you have mentioned. Both methods work, and it's really up to the team that's working on the project.

Answer (score 0):

You have two major choices :

1. You can fork the master repo on Github.
   Then you can push your branches on Github without interfering with your master repo. You will then reintegrate your finished work on the master repo with a pull request.
2. You can also push you local branch on your master repo.
   If you have cloned a Github repo, your remote is called origin. So you can push your branch to a different branch than origin/master :

   ```
   git push origin master:backup_my_branch
   ```

   That command will create a new branch on the Github repository called backup_my_branch which will contain you local master. You can of course do the same with a local branch different than master. With this solution, your colleagues can also check out backup_my_branch to work on it. How cool is that?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you explain the "git push origin master:backup_my_branch" line a bit more please? I understood shahbaz's suggestion of "git push origin dev" but not what the difference between these two suggestions is. Ta :)

Comment: @user1517244, `git push origin dev` means push local branch `dev` to `origin/dev` (which means branch `dev` on remote `origin`). On the other hand `git push origin dev:something` means push local branch `dev` to `origin/something`. Basically it lets your remote have a different branch name from your local one. I'm not sure why cexbrayat wrote that, but I can imagine you could do this if you already have a dev branch on origin.